# Django collectstatic command is not able to compile animate.css

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-apps

I tried to use [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) in one of my Django Project (if interested here's the [link](https://sportscrunch.com/)).

**Overview:**
So to deploy the code, I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, as always. Till I don't include the `animate.css` in the  `{% styles css/base-min.css %}` tag  using [django-sekizai](http://django-sekizai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)  and [django-compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor) together with the help of [GIST](https://gist.github.com/1311010).

The `collectstatic` just works fine, as soon as I include it in the project, the same command stucks.

For time being to use the `animation.css` in the project, I have directly included it with the help of

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}/css/animate.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      type="text/css" 
      media="screen" 
 />
```

But, the question remains, why is the `collectstatic` commands fails in general to compile the `animate.css`?